# Spring boot, use profiles to load files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have used [spring-boot profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to change property values for different environments, now I want to use the same approach to load different resource files, ie example I have dev_queries and prod_queries.xml with sql queries.

How can I make spring-boot load dev_queries.xml if active profile is dev and prod_queries.xml otherwise. I know that I can check the active profile but my idea is to do not add specific logic for handle this situation.

Comment: How do you load the files now? Please add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it help to externalize the filename as a custom property ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), especially [24.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties))? So that in your properties you would use:

```
# application-dev.properties
myapp.query-source=dev_queries.xml

# application-production.properties
myapp.query-source=prod_queries.xml
```

In your application beans this setting can be accessed by using the `@Value` annotation:

```java
@Value("${myapp.query-source}")
private String querySource;  // will be dev_queries.xml or prod_queries.xml
```

That way in the code where you are loading the xml file you don't have to conditionally check for the currently active profiles but can externalize that setting to the properties.

Comment: I ended doing something really similar thanks :),  @ConfigurationProperties(locations = "${myapp.query_file}")